# Are there any Database functions which allow access to other network services in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, security

I have set up a new postgres installation and have to meet the security requirements from my company.

There is one requirement were i'm not quite sure:

> Database functions which allow access to other network services (e.g. ,SMTP, HTTP, SNMP, FTP etc.), must be deleted or deactivated.
>
> *Motivation: Some database systems provide functions that are normally offered by an application server. For instance it is possible via special stored procedures to send e-mails or launch web queries to external systems.*

I have installed **postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4**. Are there any functions like this in a standard installation on **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)**?

Comment: There is nothing built-in. And only a superuser could create functions like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen that personally, so I looked up all the functions in Postgres found in the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html).

The only thing it showed remotely close was 'network address functions' in [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html) section.  Outside of that the docs don't show anything for network *access* functions.  Note this doesn't mean you can't write your own functions that access the system or OS which then can access the network.

Comment: And functions that _could_ access network services can only created by the superuser (because they would require `language c` or another untrusted language)

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql implements **Host-Based Access** control using pg_hba.conf file. This file is located in the data directory of database cluster.

The format of this file is

All parameters in a single line (Here they are numbered for convenience)

To prevent outside connection to your server,

> ```
> 1. local|remote(host|hostssl|hostnossl) connection:  local
> 2. Database                                       :  database-name or comma separated list of database names
> 3. Users                                          :  username or or comma separated list of user-names
> 4. client ip address(localhost)                   :  127.0.0.1/32
> 5. password authentication method                 :  trust | reject | md5 | password(plain text) | gss | sspi | krb5 | ident | peer | pam | ldap | radius | cert
> ```

Make sure you have the following two lines of settings as described above. The second line will **reject all remote connections**. If you want to add a range of local ip address in the first line, use for example: 192.168.84.0/24

```
local   all  all  127.0.0.1/32   md5
host    all  all  0.0.0.0/0      reject
```

Comment: That's very helpful for PCI and other compliance which require the end user to minimize their attack surface area, however in this case the poster was asking for ways that Postgres can't use network or other DB functions to go *out*, not disallow remote connections *in*.